# Excel formula to calculate the total hours worked

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on our activity in lab. I want to know how to get the total hours worked while considering the following:

- If the employee worked before 1:00pm, deduct the hour the employee came out to the time the employee came in and then deduct 1 hour for the lunch break.
- If the employee came in on and after 1:00pm, do the same computation except do not deduct 1 hour for the lunch break.

Answer (score 1):

So if `Time in` is in column A and `Time out` is in column B, you can use something like this in column C -

```
 =IF(A1<TIMEVALUE("1:00 PM"),B1-A1-TIME(1,0,0),B1-A1)
```

This is without knowing the format of your data, so adjust your format as needed to display correctly.